# Convert a list of tuples (3 elements each) to a dict {a: {b: set(c)}}

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of 3-element tuples, such as `[(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), (a2, b2, c3)]`.

I want to convert the list of tuples to a dict like

`{a1: {b1: set(c1)}, a2: {b2: set (c2, c3)}}`

Essentially, the **`c` needs to be put into a set**.

How to write a beautiful piece of code for this?

---

Here is my current code:

```
s = {}
for a,b,c in abc:
    s.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, set()).add(c)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for that structure? Why not `{(a2, b2): set([c2, c3]), ...}`, for example? Have you looked into [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)? [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: @AvinashRaj added my existing code

Comment: So what's the *problem* with your current code? If you want working code reviewed, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which will automatically create default values for missing keys, to do this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> structure = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
>>> for a, b, c in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']:
    structure[a][b].add(c)


>>> structure
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x02D16F30>, 
            {'b': defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'a': set(['r', 'z'])}), 
             'f': defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'o': set(['o'])})})
```

Note the use of `lambda`; the argument to each `defaultdict` must be a callable returning the default value to use for missing keys. However, a slightly simpler structure would make your life easier. With `{(a, b): set([c1, c2, ..]), ...}` you could use `defaultdict(set)` or just [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
>>> structure = {}
>>> for a, b, c in ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']:
    structure.setdefault((a, b), set()).add(c)


>>> structure
{('b', 'a'): set(['r', 'z']), ('f', 'o'): set(['o'])}
```

Note that `setdefault` could also be used for the first approach, but:

```
structure.setdefault(a, dict()).setdefault(b, set()).add(c)
```

is rather less readable than:

```
structure[a][b].add(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `.setdefault`. It creates new keys and assigns default value, so that we can create any level of dictionary in one statement.
Code:

```
tuple_list = [(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), (a2, b2, c3)]
new_dict = {}
for grp in tuple_list:
    new_dict.setdefault(grp[0], {}).setdefault(grp[1], set()).add(grp[2])
```